# How to grab fields in inverted commas

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, double-quotes

I have a text file which contains the following lines:

```
"user","password_last_changed","expires_in"
"jeffrey","2021-09-21 12:54:26","90 days"
"root","2021-09-21 11:06:57","0 days"
```

How can I grab two fields `jeffrey` and `90 days` from inverted commas and save in a variable.

Comment: You probably want a regex. What should the output look like, exactly?

Comment: If grep is facultative, try var=$(cut -d',' -f 1,3 < txt)     echo "${var}"

Comment: Inverted commas? You mean double quotes?

Comment: `xargs` maybe what you want, It let your handle lines one by one. Your question is not very clear, please clarify it. What do you mean by "inverted comma"? What are you trying to do? does those two column really need to be captured inside variables?

Comment: @Jamal Hossain : I have answered your question. Please check if this fulfil your need

Comment: If you want a truly compliant CSV parser, you'd do better to use Python than bash. The various answers here all have corner cases where they can be wrong when using sufficiently interesting CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `awk` is an option, you could save an array and then save the elements as individual variables.

```
$ IFS="\"" read -ra var <<< $(awk -F, '/jeffrey/{ print $1, $NF }' input_file)
$ $ var2="${var[3]}"
$ echo "$var2"
90 days
$ var1="${var[1]}"
$ echo "$var1"
jeffrey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=","

arr=( $(cat txt | head -2 | tail -1  | cut -d, -f 1,3 | tr -d '"') )
echo "${arr[0]}"
echo "${arr[1]}"
```

The result is into an array, you can access to the elements by index.

Comment: Note that `cat txt | something` is better replaced with `<txt something` or `something <txt`. It doesn't matter _too_ much for `head`, but if your first pipeline component was `tail`, the overhead of that initial `cat` would be enormous (given a large input file), because `cat` can only read front-to-back, so it would need to read all the data that `tail` just wants to ignore. By contrast, when `tail` is directly fed the real file it can skip straight to the end.

Comment: (`tail` is not the only tool that gets much less efficient when given a pipeline as input instead of a real file handle; `wc -c`, `sort`, and `tac` are three more examples that come to mind offhand)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while read -r line; do # read in line by line
    name=$(echo $line | awk -F, ' { print $1} ' | sed 's/"//g') # grap first col and strip "
    expire=$(echo $line | awk -F, ' { print $3} '| sed 's/"//g') # grap third col and strip "
    echo "$name" "$expire" # do your business
done < yourfile.txt
```

Comment: This is both buggy and inefficient. Buggy because `echo $line` can echo a list of filenames if your file contains `*` as a line. Inefficient because it's starting at least six subprocesses for every line of input when there's no reason to start _any_ at all. (Every time you run `name=$(echo $line | awk | sed)`, the shell `fork()`s off a subshell to run the `echo`; another subshell to `exec awk`, and another subshell to `exec sed`; spawning external processes is one of the slowest things a shell can do, and reliance on them is part of why shell scripts have such a reputation for being slow).

Answer (score 0):

May be this below method will help you using
`sed` and `awk` command

```
#!/bin/sh
username=$(sed -n '/jeffrey/p' demo.txt | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
echo "$username"

expires_in=$(sed -n '/jeffrey/p' demo.txt | awk -F',' '{print $3}')
echo "$expires_in"
```

**Output :**

```
jeffrey
90 days
```

**Note :**
*This above method will work if their is only distinct username*
*As far i know username are not duplicate*

Comment: There are some places where this code is not good practice. `echo $var` should always be `echo "$var"` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Also, backticks should be avoided in favor of modern POSIX-compliant command substitution: `$(...)` can be easily nested, and doesn't change the meaning of backslashes and backticks inside the enclosed space.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thanks for correcting me .. i tried on git bash that's a reason i given let me change it. Using shellcheck.in

Comment: Also, in general, it's better to avoid running two separate command substitutions -- you're running `sed` and `awk` twice as many times as you need to. Consider `IFS=$'\t' read -r username expires_in < <(awk -F, '/jeffrey/ { printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $3 }')` to not need `sed` at all and run `awk` only once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thanks bro for letting me know that values can be assigned in one single line to multiple variables

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : How about making use of `grep -Hno "jeffrey" demo.txt`  can you provide your input

Comment: `grep -o` is only going to output `jeffrey`, so that's clearly wrong. And the `-H` is used to write the filename, but the filename will only ever be `demo.txt`, so there's not a reason for that either.